# PostgreSQL query for updating same column in all tables within a schema having it

Tags: postgresql

i have 10 tables in schema icmdb2admin each table have one column named pdfname i need to update the values in the pdfname column with L1.pdfname.V1 of all tables in one loop query

```
DECLARE
    i record;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN SELECT 'icmdb2admin.' || tablename as tbp  
             FROM pg_tables 
             WHERE schemaname = 'icmdb2admin' 
               and tablename <> 'department_master' 
               and tablename <> 'year'
               and tablename <> 'user_login' 
               and tablename <> 'filetype'  
               -- and other conditions, if needed
 LOOP 
     EXECUTE  UPDATE 'i.tbp' SET "pdfname" = 'L1.'|| pdfname || '.V1'; 
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: While running this query it was not working but i get all the table name in i.tbp  update was  not working

Comment: 1) Use formatting for code, there is a special button for it. 2) You need to provide more details (English words) inside your question.

Comment: i have 10 tables in schema icmdb2admin each table have one column named pdfname i need to update the values in the pdfname column with L1.pdfname.V1 of all tables in one loop query

Comment: i AM getting error while i run this code ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 15:      EXECUTE  UPDATE 'i.tbp' SET "pdfname" = 'L1.'|| pdfname...
                                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 417

Comment: Where did you find such interesting syntax of the `EXECUTE` statement? Read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) carefully: "_`EXECUTE command-string [ INTO [STRICT] target ] [ USING expression [, ... ] ];` where **command-string** is an expression yielding a string (of type text) containing the command to be executed._"